# Resharper — fix multiple issues

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I'd like to select multiple issues in Inspection Results and fix it automatically. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest Resharper, you can batch-fix issues in a file or a project:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** since VS2010, the shortcut is Alt+Page Down, not F12.

Not that I know of. I do this by repeatedly pressing: F12, Alt+Enter.

(The F12 key moves to the next error or warning in this source file; Alt+F12 moves to the next error in the solution.)

Comment: That shortcut has apparently changed recently. In VS2010, I use Alt+PgDn (VS2010 asks to resolve a conflict when you use this) for next issue.